# Get more information from and Object type object

Tags: java, overriding

```
@Override
void func(Object obj){
    obj.foo();   // <---- Is it possible to call foo() method?
                 // Suppose I can guarantee always passing an object which has foo() method
}
```

I cannot change the function to something like

```
void func(SomeClass obj)
```

because I am overriding a method.

Comment: You could always cast.  But a need to do so indicates there may be a flaw in your design.

Comment: This smells a bit. What are your overriding? Why can't you change it?

Comment: @Spider because this is a method will automatically called by other classes in a library.

Answer (score 1):

This will cause a syntax error, since `Object` does not define the method `foo()`. However, if you're sure that the argument you're passing is actually a `SomeClass` instance, you can cast the argument:

```
@Override
void func(Object obj){
    ((SomeClass) obj).foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods -

i) Having an "instanceOf" check and then downcasting and calling the method as mentioned by Mureinik.

ii) Reflection to the rescue -

```
            Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("foo",new Class[]{});
            method.invoke(obj, null);
```